# Python Decision Trees - Creating a graphical representation of a decision tree which includes variable names

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I'm doing some work using Decision Trees on Python, using scikit learn. The classifier itself works absolutely fine, however when I create a graphical representation of this, instead of displaying the variable names, X[0], X[1]...X[n] is displayed for the variables, as in the scikit learn example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html. What makes matters more difficult is that X[0] doesn't even necessarily relate to the first column, X[1] to the second, etc, it appears like there's some process going on in assigning my variables new 'X-related' names.

How can I either put the variable names on the graphical representation, map my original variable names to their new counterparts, or ensure the new variable names are in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a argument of `tree.export_graphviz()` method called `feature_names` to specify feature names, [document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz) says:

```
feature_names : list of strings, optional (default=None)
Names of each of the features.
```

The order of feature names is the order of features in feature vector you train the model.